# SQL Specific Statement Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing quite a large query to a database and for some reason it is returning many results that do not match any of my search terms. It also seems to duplicate my results so I get the same SQL item 16 times. Any ideas why?

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
  j20e8_datsogallery AS a,
  j20e8_datsogallery_tags AS t
WHERE
  (a.id LIKE "%bear%" OR
   a.imgtitle LIKE "%bear%" OR
   a.imgtext LIKE "%bear%" OR
   a.imgauthor LIKE "%bear%" OR
   t.tag LIKE "%bear%")
ORDER BY a.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 16
```

I think it maybe something to do with the LIKE %term% section but cannot get it working at all.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your where clause will return any record that has `bear` as part of any of these fields (the `LIKE %bear%`)

Comment: The query you present is an excellemt example of a cross product.  Note that nowhere in the query do you join between tables a and t.

Comment: Shouldn't really matter but I just changed it to single quotes and still got the same results.

Comment: quotes are not the issue.  as written the correct result set will include every row in table a, multiple times.

Comment: But you are joining the tables in your query.

Comment: Aren't you missing the code to join both tables (not exactly the join sintax but a where like a.idtag=t.idtag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd make sure you qualify your join. Otherwise you'll end up with a full join, or worse, a Cartesian product from a cross join. Something along these lines:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
j20e8_datsogallery AS a
JOIN j20e8_datsogallery_tags AS t ON a.ID = t.GalleryID
WHERE
...
ORDER BY a.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 16
```

Also, consider using a `FULLTEXT INDEX` ... it could combine all those columns into a single index, and would make searching all of them quite functional.

A `FULLTEXT INDEX` in MySql can be used to 'combine' several different columns into one big pile of text, which you can then `MATCH()` columns `AGAINST` search terms.

To create a `FULLTEXT INDEX`, you can simply use the `CREATE INDEX` syntax documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html).

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX FDX_datsogallery 
ON j20e3_datsogallery ( id, imgtitle, imgtext, imgauthor )
```

You can then use it in a query with the `MATCH() ... AGAINST` statements, which are documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM j20e8_datsogallery AS a
WHERE MATCH( id, imgtitle, imgtext, imgauthor ) AGAINST( 'bear' )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seemed to work. Could you please elaborate in your answer the reason to do a FULLTEXT INDEX and how to do this?

Comment: Added some info about `FULLTEXT INDEX`es

Answer (score 1):

It's bringing back multiples because:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM j20e8_datsogallery AS a, j20e8_datsogallery_tags AS t
```

brings back ***every*** combination of records from the two tables on it's own.  So `bear` in one table joins to every record in the other table.

You need to specify a relationship between the tables, preferably using an explicit `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You have a cross join between the two tables, which means every row in `a` will be joined with every row in `t`, and as I said in my comment, you will be getting every record that has `bear` in one of those fields.

**you should have a join condition somewhere. Then do your filtering.**

Answer (score 0):

Your results are a cartesian product of your data, because you don't have a join condition. This means that it is returning every combination of matching rows from `a` and `t`.

You probably need to so something like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
  j20e8_datsogallery AS a,
  INNER JOIN j20e8_datsogallery_tags AS t ON a.id = t.a_id --(or whatever the foreign key is)
WHERE
  (a.id LIKE "%bear%" OR
   a.imgtitle LIKE "%bear%" OR
   a.imgtext LIKE "%bear%" OR
   a.imgauthor LIKE "%bear%" OR
   t.tag LIKE "%bear%")
ORDER BY a.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 16
```